# Broadcast from external controller to internal controller is not working

Tags: angularjs, broadcast

In my AngularJS application there are 2 controllers: `ExternalCtrl` and `LoginModalCtrl`.

`ExternalCtrl` constains `LoginModalCtrl`. `ExternalCtrl` all `broadcast` method to give singal to `LoginModalCtrl` in order to show modal, but it's not working. My code is attached below.

**Why $scope.$on method is not started?**

*Controller LoginModalCtrl*

```
app.controller('LoginModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', function($scope, $uibModal) {
    var $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.modalInstance = null;

    $ctrl.animationsEnabled = true;

    $ctrl.open = function(size, parentSelector) {
        var parentElem = parentSelector ?
            angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-login' + parentSelector)) : undefined;

        $ctrl.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-header',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            templateUrl: 'loginModalContent.html',
            controller: 'LoginModal2Ctrl',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            backdropClass: "modal-backdrop",
            size: size,
            backdrop: true,
            appendTo: parentElem,

            resolve: {
                items: function() {
                    return $ctrl.items;
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $ctrl.scope = $scope;

    $scope.$on('$showLoginWindow', function(event, args) {
       //$ctrl.open();
       console.log('on showLoginWindow ...');
    });
}]);
```

*Controller ExternalCtrl*

```
'use strict';
app.controller('ExternalCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'authenticationService',
    function($scope, $location, authenticationService) {


        $scope.logout = function() {
            authenticationService.logOut();
            $location.path('/');
        };

        $scope.authentication = authenticationService.authentication;

        $scope.$broadcast('$showLoginWindow');
        console.log('broadcasting showLoginWindow ...');
    }
]);
```

UPDATE1:
I added the line as first line of each controllers: "Initializing  XXXCtrl".

Now when page is started I see following messages in console:

```
Initializing ExternalCtrl ExternalCtrl.js:14 
broadcasting showLoginWindow ... 
... 
LoginModalCtrl.js:2 Initializing LoginModalCtrl
```

Comment: Is`ExternalCtrl` initialised first and then `LoginModalCtrl` or vice versa? Are you seeing in console the `broadcasting showLoginWindow ...`?

Comment: Yes, I see message "broadcasting showLoginWindow ..." in console.

Comment: Could you confirm me the first question? Which controller is initialised first? That might be the problem

Comment: Im not sure how to check which one is initialized first, could you advice me how to check it?

Comment: Sure. In your `LoginModalCtrl` place a `console.log('LoginModalCtrl initialised'); before the `$scope.$on(....` and do exactly the same in `ExternalCtrl` (remember change the message)

Comment: See which message gets printed the first

Comment: I added UPDATE 1, is it ok for you?

Comment: OK, that's ok. One last question: Is `ExternalCtrl` "managing" an element (html) which is outer to an element which is "managed" by `LoginModalCtrl`?? If not, the `broadcast` of `ExternalCtrl` will never be "seen" by `LoginModalCtrl`.

Comment: ExternalCtrl  is attached to BODY tag, so ExternalCtrl is external to LoginModalCtrl , right?

Comment: Looking at your code and console.logs, it looks like your `ExternalController` is instantiated first and then your `LoginModalCtrl`, and so the broadcast message from `ExternalController` will never reach `LoginModalCtrl`.

Comment: If you only want to broadcast after logout has happened, you could do `$scope.$broadcast('$showLoginWindow');` from your `$scope.logout` function.

Comment: Ok, I added timeout, and broadcast is startea after 500 miliseconds , and it works. Is it good solution?

Comment: I think it's OK, though If I were you, I would have used a service if possible for communicating the controllers (of course, it depends totally of your specific sutation).